# Why does mypy raise error when I run it with pre-commit for django-reset-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to automate my tests and code static analysis with pre-commit.My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` is like below:

```yaml
# .
# .
# .
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: 'v0.910'
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        args: [--no-strict-optional, --ignore-missing-imports]
        exclude: "[a-zA-Z]*/[a-zA-Z]*/(migrations)/(.)*"
        additional_dependencies: [
            'tokenize-rt,
            'djangorestframework-stubs',
            'django-stubs',
        ]
```

The `pyproject.toml` is:

```
[tool.mypy]
python_version = "3.8"
plugins = ["mypy_django_plugin.main", "mypy_drf_plugin.main"]

[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = "api.shop.shop.settings"
```

When I run the `pre-commit run --all-files` I get the following error:

```
Error constructing plugin instance of NewSemanalDjangoPlugin

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/bin/mypy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_entry())
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypy/__main__.py", line 11, in console_entry
    main(None, sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
  File "mypy/main.py", line 87, in main
  File "mypy/main.py", line 165, in run_build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 179, in build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 229, in _build
  File "mypy/build.py", line 475, in load_plugins
  File "mypy/build.py", line 453, in load_plugins_from_config
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/main.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.django_context = DjangoContext(django_settings_module)
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/django/context.py", line 88, in __init__
    apps, settings = initialize_django(self.django_settings_module)
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypy_django_plugin/django/context.py", line 72, in initialize_django
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/alipqb/.cache/pre-commit/repo94ds7xs0/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

But I have installed both `djangoresetframework` and `djangorestframework-stubs` in my environment. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 8):

pre-commit runs its tools in isolated environments, you can control the dependencies (as you've seen already it seems (!)) from the `additional_dependencies` as stated in the [mirrors-mypy readme](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy#using-mypy-with-pre-commit)

it looks like the `mypy_django_plugin` is missing dependencies -- notably it tries to import `django` and `rest-framework` so you'll need to make sure to include those inside `additional_dependencies`

note that you don't need `tokenize-rt` -- that was just an example from the README so you can remove that

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can run `mypy` manually but with `pre-commit` I get this error. I know the problem is with settings in `pyproject.toml` or the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` but I don't know the real location of error. I have also read the documents for all of them and I added all possible configurations. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: oh sorry if it wasn't clear, the tl;dr is add the missing things to `additional_dependencies`

Comment: Once I add additional dependencies then mypy does not detect any of the packages installed in the django project